# Node.js streams and data disappearing

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been playing with Readable and Transforming streams, and I can't solve a mystery of disappearing lines.

Consider a text file in which the lines contain sequential numbers, from 1 to 20000:

```
$ seq 1 20000 > file.txt
```

I create a `Readable` stream and a `LineStream` (from a library called *byline*: `npm install byline`; I'm using version 4.1.1):

```
var file = (require('fs')).createReadStream('file.txt');
var lines = new (require('byline').LineStream)();
```

Consider the following code:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  lines.on('readable', function() {
    var line;
    while (null !== (line = lines.read())) {
      console.log(line);
    } 
  });
}, 1500);

setTimeout(function() {
  file.on('readable', function() {
    var chunk;
    while (null !== (chunk = file.read())) {
      lines.write(chunk);
    }
  }); 
}, 1000);
```

Notice that it first attaches a listener to the `'readable'` event of the `file` Readable stream, which writes to the `lines` stream, and only half a second later it attaches a listener to the `'readable'` event of the `lines` stream, which simply prints lines to the console.

If I run this code, it will only print 16384 (which is 2^14) lines and stop. It won't finish the file. However, if I change the 1500ms timeout to 500ms -- effectively swapping the order in which the listeners are attached, it will happily print the whole file.

I've tried playing with highWaterMark, with specifying an amount of bytes to read from the file stream, attaching listeners to other events of the lines stream, all in vain.

What can explain this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this behaviour can be explained with two things:

1. How you use streams.
2. How `byline` works.

What you do is manual piping. The problem with it is that it doesn't respect `highWaterMark` and forces the whole to be buffered.

All this causes `byline` to behave badly. See this: https://github.com/jahewson/node-byline/blob/master/lib/byline.js#L110-L112. It means that it stops pushing lines, when buffers length > highWaterMark. But this doesn't make any sense! It doesn't prevent memory usage growth (lines are still stored in special line buffer), but stream doesn't know about these lines and if it ends in overflown state, they will be lost forever.

What you can do:

1. Use `pipe`
2. Modify `highWaterMark` : `lines._readableState.highWaterMark = Infinity;`
3. Stop using `byline`

Comment: Thanks!! That totally explains it. I had skimmed through byline's source code but I believe my lack of experience with Node.js (and particularly its streams) made it hard for me to see that issue.